# How to build regex to capture all possible matching group

Tags: regex

I have a string which contains the data in xml format like as

```
str = "<p><a>_a_10gd_</a><a>_a_xy8a_</a><a>_a_1020_</a><a>_a_dfa7_</a><a>_a_ABCD_</a></p>";
```

What I am trying to do is that I want to capture `_abc__(Value)__` from all possible mach. I have tried it that way

Let say I am doing this in JavaScript :-

```
var regex = /_a_(.+)_/g ;
var str = "<a>_a_10gd_</a><a>_a_xy8a_</a><a>_a_1020_</a><a>_a_dfa7_</a><a>_a_ABCD_</a>";

while(m = regex.exec(str)){
     console.log(m[1]); // m[1] should contains each mach 
}
```

I want to get all maching group in an array like this :-

```
var a = ['10gd', 'xy8a', '1020', 'dfa7', 'ABCD'];
```

Please tell me that what will be required regex and explain it also because I am new to regex and their capturing group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `(.+)` to `(.+?)` see:

```js
var regex = /_a_(.+?)_/g ;
var str = "<a>_a_10gd_</a><a>_a_xy8a_</a><a>_a_1020_</a><a>_a_dfa7_</a><a>_a_ABCD_</a>";

while(m = regex.exec(str)){
     console.log(m[1]); // m[1] should contains each mach 
}
```

for more information about greediness, see [What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

Comment: Thanks for your answer , can you explain me how ? is working in regex here because as I know ? is used for optional thing

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to accept only characters except _ before the _ (instead of . which you have used), like so:

```
var regex = /_a_([^_]+)_/g ;
```